# How can I figure out where a cookie's being set from?

Tags: cookies

I need some kind of tool that alerts me whenever a cookie is set and tells me where that cookie is being set from (eg some javascript or http headers). Google is failing me. I need to know exactly what line of code is setting that cookie, simply telling me "a cookie has been set" isn't enough. Is there a program/browser extension that will do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the Firecookie add-on for Firebug in Firefox.

Comment: This is helpful, but it cannot be used to see where a cookie is being set from?